# Error Build with QT application for android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm developing application for android via QT creator. Some what was added and application not compiling. Here compile output:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
Makefile:4694: recipe for target 'libmagnet_construct.so' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libmagnet_construct.so] Error 1
09:41:04: The process "C:\DEVELOPMENT\IDEs\Qt5.3.1\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project magnet_builder (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.3.1))
When executing step 'Make'
```

Please, tell me, what a problem?

Comment: Some one help me, i don't found answer yet!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the CreateProcess error because cp isn't installed. The Makefile is specifying to use cp to copy files. You can get cp and other utilities you may find desired by Makefiles by downloading and installing [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys).